# Why doesn't my function get the auto-completion properly in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I want to use my own custom function and hence I created the following class, which is subclass from `NSObject`, like:

```
class ServeStatsTable: NSObject {...}
```

And in the class above, I defined the following method:

```
func serveTableViewHeader(tableView: UITableView!, number: String, info: NSDictionary, color: UIColor!) -> UIView! {...}
```

However, when I tried to call the method above from within another class, which is subclass from `UIViewController`, the method didn't react to the auto-completion in Xcode, with the following completion:

```
ServeStatsTable.serveTableViewHeader(tableView)
```

And so I modified it to the following correct method call:

```
ServeStatsTable.serveTableViewHeader(tableView, number: "1", info: info, color: UIColor.orangeColor())
```

but then, the Xcode spits out an error: `Extra argument 'number'...`.

So I think I even cannot define the method properly.

But then how to define the method properly? The error occurred on another function within the class.

And finally, when I tried to make auto-completion in Xcode, it shows the following pop-up:

[image]

If it's not the argument list, then what's the left side code from `serveTableViewHeader` mean? It looks like the argument here is `self: ServeStatsTable`, which is not what I looked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServeStatsTable` is a class, but `serveTableViewHeader(number:info:color:)` is an instance method, not a class method.  So `ServeStatsTable.serveTableViewHeader(tableView, number: "1", info:info, color:UIColor.orangeColor())` is not a valid expression.

The `Extra argument 'number'` error is due to your use of a colon instead of a comma after `tableView` here:

```
ServeStatsTable.serveTableViewHeader(tableView: number: "1", info: info, color: UIColor.orangeColor())
                                              ^
```

If you want to make it a class method, so you call it on the class instead of on an instance, put `class` in the method declaration, like this:

```
class ServeStatsTable: NSObject {

    class func serveTableViewHeader(tableView: UITableView!, number: String, info: NSDictionary, color: UIColor!) -> UIView! {...}

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. As to the `Extra argument` error, it was a typo when writing the question, but the original code used the comma and still got me the error. I fixed it.